# Fedora 17, WebGL, intel integrated graphics

Tags: fedora, chrome

I have troubles with getting started WebGL in Google chrome. This is the info about my GPU from `about:gpu`:

```
GPU0 VENDOR = 0x8086 [Intel Corporation],
   DEVICE= 0x0116 [2nd Generation Core Processor Family
                   Integrated Graphics Controller]
```

I made some research and did checked enabled in `about:flags` the following properties:

- WebGL
- accelerated 2D canvas
- Override software rendering list

Also I tried to start chrome with `-ignore-gpu-blacklist` but still WebGL and hardware acceleration is unavailable. I know that WebGL need OpenGL at least 2.0. Then I searched in repositories and found only two libraries which were seemed like what I need, I installed them, but still no result.

What do I need to make it work ?